# briefly + ver or verb+briefly

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I read many examples in English about using the word `briefly`. However, I found that all the examples, that I read, used `verb + briefly`. My question is can I use it as `briefly + verb`. For example,

> This paragraph briefly describes the idea of .....

or

I must use it like this:

> This paragraph describes, briefly, the idea of ....

Comment: native speakers do, but it may not be correct.

Comment: I prefer your first sentence—it sounds more affirmative. (In the second sentence, *briefly* seems unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can go in either position, and in general that has no significant impact on meaning.